# On normalized 2-cocycle

Tags: gr.group-theory, homological-algebra, finite-groups, cohomology, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a group acts trivially on an abelian group $A$. Let
$\varepsilon $ be a normalized 2-cocycle in $ Z^{2}(G,A)$. Assume
that $G=H_{1} \times H_{2}$ and let $\varepsilon_{1}=res_{H_{1}\times
H_{1}}(\varepsilon) \in Z^{2}(H_{1},A)$ and $\varepsilon_{2}=res_{H_{2}\times
H_{2}}(\varepsilon) \in Z^{2}(H_{2},A)$. What is the  expression of $\varepsilon$ depending on $\varepsilon_{1}$ and $\varepsilon_{2}$?.

Any help would be appreciated so much. Thank you all.

Comment: You cannot in general recover $\varepsilon $ from $\varepsilon _1$ and $\varepsilon _2$ (think of the Künneth formula).

Comment: I asked this question after seeing Proposition 1 of  [Tahara](https://sci-hub.tw/https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01181625)